Can't ping two Linux devices on the same subnet but can ping the others and the gateway
I have two CentOS devices running on UTM in my Mac, with IP addresses on same subnet, but they can't ping each other and yet they can ping gateway, etc.
My Mac can ping both devices and vice-versa but they can't with each other.
I tried disabling firewall, change SELinux settings, change IPS of both device, change the network interface from bridged to shared and then again back to bridged.
Nothing worked so far.

Are your VMs using a NAT address?

i was using bridged network not nat
